# Lotus Notes Domino Application stopped working after changing Server's IP configuration

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

Our company just merged with a smaller company that we are now integrating in our network. After adapting the IP number of the server to our range, the application that this company was using ever since, doesn't work correctly anymore.

Unfortunately the IT company that had been giving support to them doesn't exist anymore. Nobody of my company has any experience with Lotus Notes nor do we have ways to see the code. We thought of keeping their software solution alive until the functionality will be covered by our ERP.

The only change that was made is the change of the IP Address.

Any reflections or hints on this?

Comment: This is not a programming question. Try on serverfault.com

Comment: Check the log.nsf file (notes log) for error messages upon running your server and your application on it. This file is located at root folder of your Domino server.

Comment: You need a better description than "doesn't work correctly anymore".  What is it supposed to do? What does it do instead? What is the EXACT text of any error messages that are displayed, and what EXACTLY is the user (or agent) doing when the error message occurs. Even with this, IMHO it is really unlikely that you're going to be successful in solving this problem without engaging a qualified Notes/Domino consultant to do some hands-on troubleshooting. There are just are too many things that could be going on.

Comment: Hi @RichardSchwartz below I discribed what i going on. A js File is not found inside one nsf archive where it is supposed to be and it throws an error. By coincidence I found that this file exists, but with a slightly different name. (with an aditional 's') The strange thing is that these archives can't really be edited. At least nobody here has editors to do so.

Answer (score 2):

The domino server is quite sensitive to an IP address change if it has been configured with that instead of a dns name.

A few things to try:

1. Ping the domino server name from the cmd line on the server.  It should resolve.  If it doesn’t then either add an entry to dns or add a hosts entry.
2. Check the notes.ini file on the server for any reference to the old ip.  Change this to the new ip (having made a backup of the original file).
3. Using a notes client, open the names.nsf and find the servers view and then the entry for the server.  Check it for any references to the old ip and change them.
4. On the notes client open the local names.nsf and under “advanced” look for the connections and locations.  Change any references to the old ip addresses here.

Ideally, you should refer to the domino server by its domino name (not the os server name) and this should be resolvable in DNS.

Comment: Thank you Rob for this hint that actually brought us a bit further. We now mapped the original host name to the new IP Address. The notes.ini file didn't contain any reference to the old IP. We edited the local host file to the new IP adress. When analysing the errors it throws in the navigators tool (what I didn't do yesterday), I can see 2 JS errors that pop up when entering into the Edit mode, which makes me think that there is some underlying permission issue behind. Keep in mind that we changed from WORKGROUP to DOMAIN

Comment: So you did more than just change the IP.  Try loading the problem .js files directly with the browser (http://serverblahblah/.../whatever.js) and see what errors the browser returns.  404?  500?  Access denied?  Connection timed out?  Changing Windows permission won't affect how users interact with a Notes (NSF) application.  It *can* affect whether the Domino service can access the non-NSF (i.e. html/js/css/etc.) files in the file system.

Comment: Thank you Duston for the interest in this case! It's error 404! So the js-files seems to be actually missing. Its a mistery how something can be missing as nothing had been touched. BUT I had a lucky guess: The js that is supposed to be in that nsf archive should be called: FuncionesFormulario.js - so I thought maybe a letter was somehow lost and I checked for FuncionesFormularios.js and voilá that file actually exists! The question is, how can I change its name inside that archive? I was looking for online edeting tools but can't find any.

Comment: Before you go changing anything, I think you need to be absolutely sure that you understand the error. What is the full URL for the transaction that is generating the 404? Use the network debug feature in your browser if necessary, as the generated HTML may be only showing you a truncated URL. What is the hostname or IP in the URL? I would also look at the Internet Site web rules that are configured on the server, as there could be a redirect for FuctionesFormulario or FuctionesFormularios.

Comment: As for what you need to edit it, it is Domino Designer. There is no free online tool for this. If you want to maintain a Domino application, you have to have the licensed tools. The company you acquired should have had the licenses, but if they had allowed their support from HCL (or previously IBM) to expire, you will either have to purchase the licenses or engage a consultant who has a licensed version of the software and can work on your systems.

Comment: Richard, as suggested by Duston, I had used the url that points directly to the js-file that was threw the error I saw in the navigators console. That 404 error tells me that that js file isn't around. There is a js-file with almost that name and I would love to change the nsf archive to point to that js, but I don't know any method to edit it without a Lotus Client

Comment: @Barnabeck You said above that the application "doesn't work anymore", which implies that it worked previously. You also said that the only thing that was changed was the IP address. A mis-named js element referred to from the app's HTML cannot explain this. So either it didn't work previously, or there is more to this than you have figured out so far.